# Como criar 2 forms simultaneamente em Django e configurar a views

Tags: django, django-templates

O que eu quero fazer é criar 2 forms simultaneamente, em apenas uma pagina 'index.html'. Um seria apenas um form normal que enviará uma mensagem para contato, e o outro é um registro que preciso salvar no banco de dados.
Até o momento consegui criar só usando um  form, dessa maneira.

```
class IndexView(FormView):
template_name = 'index.html'
form_class = ContatoForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['servicos'] = Servico.objects.order_by('?').all()
    context['funcionarios'] = Funcionario.objects.order_by('?').all()
    context['portfolios'] = Portfolio.objects.order_by('?').all()
    context['testimonials'] = Testimonial.objects.order_by('?').all()

    return context

def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
    form.send_mail()
    messages.success(self.request, 'E-mail enviado com sucesso')
    return super(IndexView, self).form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)

def form_invalid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
    messages.error(self.request, 'Erro ao enviar e-mail')

    return super(IndexView, self).form_invalid(form, *args, **kwargs)
```

Agora eu precisava adicionar um outro form, que é esse

```
class RegistroModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Registro
    fields = ['nome', 'email', 'phone', 'area']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viva, podes criar multiples forms, existe ainda inlineformset_factory entre outros, depende do caso de uso. Mesmo aqui em nesta "class based generic views", podes utilizar outra diferente que se adapte melhor ao teu caso que Django disponibiliza, como por exemplo: View, ListView, TemplateView, CreateView, DeleteView, UpdateView que podes importar de django.views.generic. Ou simplesmente utilizar uma função tua que implica fazeres mais código e validações que estas class base já fazem por ti.

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class IndexView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = ContatoForm
    form_class_adicional = RegistroModelForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = { 
            'form': self.form_class,
            'form_new': self.form_class_adicional(),
            'servicos': Servico.objects.order_by('?').all(),
            'funcionarios': Funcionario.objects.order_by('?').all(),
            'portfolios': Portfolio.objects.order_by('?').all(),
            'testimonials': Testimonial.objects.order_by('?').all()
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.form_class(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            form_new = self.form_class_adicional(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            # aqui Django valida o teu form, neste caso só os dois válidos irá gravar, mas podes mudar esta lógica
            if form.is_valid() and form_new.is_valid(): 
                form.save()
                form_new.save()
                form.send_mail() # envias o email
                #messages.success(self.request, 'E-mail enviado com sucesso') # esta mensagem colocas na função send_mail
                #messages.error(self.request, 'Erro ao enviar e-mail')        # esta mensagem colocas na função send_mail
            return redirect('index')
        return redirect('index')
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="." enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    {{ form_new }}
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Gravar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Eu precisaria fazer uma filtragem também para saber qual forms está indo pro form_valid para poder fazer uma ação ou não, porque são formulários diferentes e independentes que estão na mesma página. Enquanto o RegistroModelForm é para salvar no banco de dados, o ContatoForm é para enviar uma mensagem para mim, ai como faria a filtragem? também tenho outro problema, o template já está pronto e montando em html, no caso eu só reutilizaria os campos mas não criaria denovo.

Comment: Olá viva para a tua outra questão, habitualmente não utilizo o FormView class based, utilizo o CreateView ou UpdateView. Editei a minha resposta do teu exemplo com multiplos forms. Terás de fazer algo assim.